# How to use plugin add_meta_box similar using in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a form in front same as using in wp-admin.

there is meta boxes using .

I want to konw how I can use that meta box in front page.

right now I am using

```
do_action( 'do_meta_boxes', $post_type, 'normal', $post );
```

but it's not working as $wp_meta_boxes; is null in front end.

How I call the boxes in front end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which post type you use ... i mean post, page or custom post type

Comment: I am using eventon plugin and post type ajde_events

Answer (score 1):

I think meta boxes are meant for the **administrative interface** only and the corresponding actions are only fired in the dashboard.
Instead I suggest you use a normal form, like in the example below (use this code in you page template). Note that you **must** sanitize the data comming from the form before saving it to the database!

```
<?php

// submit the form
if(isset($_POST['submit_form'])){

// IMPORTANT: SANITIZE AND VALIDATE THE POST VALUES HERE

// update the post meta
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'lastname', $_POST['lastname']);

}

?>

<?php
// get the post meta
$firstname = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'firstname', true);
$lastname = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'lastname', true);
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo esc_attr($firstname);?>">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo esc_attr($lastname);?>">
    <button type="submit" name="submit_form" value="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```